# How can I change the y-axis range based on a callback when the x-axis range changes in Bokeh?

Tags: python, charts, visualization, bokeh

I would like to change the visible range of the y-axis each time when the x-axis range changes. But something does not seem to work, panning and changing the x-axis range does not seem to invoke the callback or something is wrong with the callback?

```
x = list(range(100))
y = list(np.random.randint(-10, 10, 100))
y = np.cumsum(y)
p1 = figure(title="Random", width=600, height=600)
p1.line(x, y, color="red")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(yrange=p1.y_range), code="""
           yrange.start=-10;
           yrange.end=10;""")
                
p1.x_range.js_on_change("end", callback)

show(p1)
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood it, but if you choose the same value for the `100` in `x`, and the last value in definition of `y`, x-axis is changing (both indeed).

Comment: @Memristor, sorry, I edited the code, I want the y-axis range to reset to between -10 and 10 whenever the x-axis range changes. But nothing is happening...

Comment: I have managed to cap the y-axis using `p1.y_range = Range1d(-10, 10, bounds="auto")` at the end of the code (before, `show`), not sure that is what you want. `Range1d` is on `bokeh.models`.

Comment: No, I am trying to get the callback to work. Ultimately, I want to set the y-axis range to the min and max of the actual data between the x-Axis min and max. This requires me to be able to set the y-axis range **inside** the callback.

Comment: I think you need to put your data in a `ColumnDataSource` class, then feed this to the `CustomJS` dict to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-ranging to show the appropriate range of y-values depending on the displayed portion of x-axis has been implemented for the HoloViews Bokeh backend [here](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/main/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py#L1012).

While this isn't a simple, pure Bokeh example, this does show that the behavior you want is possible using `CustomJS` ([this line](https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/blob/main/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py#L1071) in particular seems relevant). Hope that is helpful!